# Find the minimum number of coins needed to make an amount of money

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a dollar amount, how can I find the minimum number of coins needed for that amount?

Example input: $1.21

Example output: [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01]

I was thinking of backtracking option with Java

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Many common homework questions have been asked before -- coin change algorithms have been asked and answered many times. The help page for stackoverflow suggests searching for your question before asking (although that's not always so easy, because sometimes finding the right search terms is tricky). For further feedback, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop through the coins from largest to smallest and use as many as possible each time. Note that it is better to use cents to avoid floating-point issues.

```
static List<Integer> minCoins(int cents){
    int[] coins = {25, 10, 5, 1};
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int coin: coins){
        if(cents == 0) break;
        result.addAll(Collections.nCopies(cents / coin, coin));
        cents %= coin;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/fqULug)

Note that for the general case of any set of coins, the above greedy algorithm does not always work and dynamic programming is required.

Comment: what about coins = {8,7,1} and target = 14, your greedy algorithm would find {8,1,1,1,1,1,1} instead of {7,7}.

Comment: @maraca This question is not about such coins, though. If it required a solution for any set of coins, then dynamic programming would be required. However, that is not the case here.